# Can a Json Web Token be faked or impersonated?

Tags: javascript, jwt

I have get the JWT authentication up and running in my react-native project. Now every request I make, token will be included in header as `authorization`.

To my understanding, when the server receives my token, it will be decoded into something like:

```
{ sub: user.id, iat: timestamp, email: user.email }
```

Then the server will recognize me based on that `user.id`.

But since there's only the token included in the header, no `userId` in the header, how can the server know that I am really the one with that id? Say a hacker got my token, then can he fake as me and talk to the server?

Comment: [5 Easy Steps to Understanding JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec#.jeug98kir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to prevent such tokens from being stolen in-transit is via Transport Level Security, specifically SSL.  The HTTPS connection is established *first,* before tokens are exchanged between the two systems.

There are potentially other solutions that can also be used to prevent token theft, such as [Token Binding Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/91/slides/slides-91-uta-2.pdf) and [Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

To provide additional security, tokens are often time-limited.  [Reference Tokens](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/) can be revoked on demand, without having to wait for them to time out.